# Full height "sidebars" with main content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to achieve the below scenario:

[image: What I am trying to achieve]

I am using the below HTML and CSS code. **([See JSFiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/se9qutyz/))**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
            <div class="col-xs-2 sidebar"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8"> Main Content That goes a long way down on the page.. <div style="height:2000px"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 sidebar left"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{ height: 100%; }
.sidebar{
    border-right:1px solid red;
    padding:0;
    min-height:100% !important;
    position:relative;
    background:gray;
}
.sidebar .left{
    border-left:1px solid red;
}
```

Now the above code outputs something like this:

[image: What I have now, with my current code]

**UPDATE**
Put the exact code from the fiddle in the question, there was some misunderstanding in the answers given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If browser compatibility is not a concern, you can use [Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```
.wrap { 
    height:100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.sidebar{
    border-right:1px solid red;
    padding:0;
    min-height:100% !important;
    position:relative;
    background:gray;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.sidebar .left{
    width: 200px;
    border-left:1px solid red;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.col-xs-8 {
    border-left:1px solid blue;
    border-right:1px solid blue;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbr3mo36/)

Comment: You easily skipped the very large column in the middle, try this and you see: http://jsfiddle.net/zbr3mo36/1/

Comment: @arnoudhgz what do you mean?

Comment: My content in col-xs-8 is getting mixed up with col-xs-2 and is generally looking really weird. Like all the content is getting mixed.

Comment: Sounds like you have an unclosed `div` or something then. I do not experience that issue in the Fiddle I provided.

Comment: @APAD1 Add style="height:2000px" to col-xs-8 in your fiddle, and it still doesn't work? Can't see how this fixed anything..?

Comment: @APAD1, I mean where did you put the `Main Content That goes a long way down on the page.. <div style="height:2000px"></div>` I am missing a lot from the 2000px height there was in the first place (using Chrome btw)

Comment: You're not making any sense. That `height:2000px` was added by someone else, not me.

Comment: @APAD1 In my Fiddle there is a div with height 2000px in the main content, to show how the sidebars responds to long content - since that is what I am asking to fix. If I add height 2000px in your fiddle, it isn't working.

Comment: In your question, you stated that you wanted the 3 columns to all have the same height, that is what my answer does, the height of any one div is completely irrelevant. If you want something different you need to restate your question clearer.

Comment: Yes, they do, and my answer does what your image shows.

Comment: @APAD1, oliver, the info in the initial jsfiddle and the question were different, this is why there we all didn't understand eachother exactly. 

**APAD1** look also at the jsfiddle in the question, **oliver** please do not post different cases in the fiddle and the question

Comment: When I get downvoted for no reason, that's about the time I move on. Good luck with your issue!

Comment: ^ Some people are trolls

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this with a little bit of jQuery. I had just recently launched my website, i have 2 sidebar and 1 content same as yours. And i am using bootstrap as well. Give those both sidebar a same class `.sidebar`

Create a function like this:

```
function sidebarHeight() {
  var containerHeight = $('.wrap').height();
  $('.sidebar').height(containerHeight);
}
```

And then run your function on window load and resize

```
$(window).load(sidebarHeight);
$(window).resize(sidebarHeight);
```

You can see the demo on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/monkeytempal/pen/bpMJWo).
I writtern a short tutorial on this on my blog here [Andwecode.com](http://andwecode.com/full-height-sidebar-jquery/)